# Get data from the port of the switch a pc is connected to

Tags: windows, ip-address, mac-address, switching

I'm developing an inventory and audit of laboratories in our school. It needs to keep track if there are transfers of PCs in each laboratory. Each lab has its own network. So it's not even possible to know the transfers if by ip address alone. Is it possible to get data from the port of the switch the PCs are connected to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your switches support SNMP. You can track the PCs by the MAC addresses of their network interface cards (as long as they don't change). There is a few OIDs that might be interesting for getting this info. First of them is:

`1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1`  (dot1dTpFdbAddress):

> A unicast MAC address for which the bridge has forwarding and/or filtering information.

If your network is really simple like one switch for the lab, no VLANs, etc. you can just walk the first OID and get the MAC addresses from the switch, cross-reference them with your database of PCs and check whatever you need to check.

If you do have VLANs or there are multiple labs connected to the single switch you would need to go deeper and find the port to which the PC is connected.

`1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2`  (dot1dTpFdbPort):

> Either the value "0", or the port number of the port on which a frame having a source address equal to the value of the corresponding instance of dot1dTpFdbAddress has been seen.

`1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.4.1.2`  (dot1dBasePortIfIndex):

> The value of the instance of the ifIndex object, defined in MIB-II, for the interface corresponding to this port.

`1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1`  (ifName):

> The textual name of the interface.  The value of this object should be the name of the interface as assigned by the local device and should be suitable for use in commands entered at the device's `console'.

Below is the example (on some Linksys switch) of doing this manually but you can easily write a script to do just that and return the list of MAC addresses and ports they're learned on.

```
# snmpwalk -v2c -c "your_community" switch.example.com 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.64.85.57.242.44.224 = Hex-STRING: 40 55 39 F2 2C E0
```

Walking trough this OID will list all MAC addresses the switch has learned. In my example for simplicity there is only one MAC address (40:55:39:f2:2c:e0). Next you want to find the number of the bridge port that MAC address:

```
# snmpget -v2c -c "your_community" switch.example.com 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2.64.85.57.242.44.224
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.64.85.57.242.44.224 = INTEGER: 6
```

The additional numbers you see in the OID are the dotted-decimal representation of the MAC address. After this you get the interface index from the bridge port number and finally the interface name (port name).

```
# snmpget -v2c -c "your_community" switch.example.com 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.4.1.2.6
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.1.4.1.2.6 = INTEGER: 6
# snmpget -v2c -c "your_community" switch.example.com 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.6
IF-MIB::ifName.6 = STRING: Port6
```

And you found out that a host with 40:55:39:f2:2c:e0 MAC address is connected to Port6. If you're dealing with some higher quality equipment (like Cisco) you should know that they might keep separate instances for each VLAN and use something called SNMP Community String Indexing where you add the Vlan index to your community string like this (for Vlan 123):

```
# snmpwalk -v2c -c "your_community"@123 switch.example.com 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1
```